# chef rails 4 ruby 2.1 rbenv capistrano shared bin passenger file missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, passenger, chef-infra

We are relatively new to using chef to deploy our applications.  Currently, an odd issue we are experiencing and have yet to find a solution for relates to our `bin/passenger` configuration file.  For some reason when the server is constructed with chef it does not exist or chef is not creating it.  Maybe capistrano is not creating it... We are a bit dumbfounded by this one.

As you can see from the attached image, we know the file is not there.  All of our current scripts match 4 other servers that are running successfully but for some reason this new build will not create the file.  Or TBH, we are completely missing some steps.  It has been some very long nights trying to get this going.

> We used chef to build the server and we are using capistrano to deploy to the box

Anyone have any thoughts? Need more information? Pointers?

Our current `config/deploy.rb` file:

```
set :application, 'digest'

set :scm, :git
set :repo_url, '{omitted private repo}'
set :branch, 'experiment/cap'
set :deploy_to, '/home/apps/api'

set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :user, 'deploy'
set :use_sudo, false

set :rbenv_type, :system
set :rbenv_ruby, '2.1.0'
set :rbenv_path, '/opt/rbenv'

namespace :deploy do

  desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      execute "mkdir -p #{release_path}/tmp ; touch #{release_path}/tmp/restart.txt"
    end
  end

  desc 'Create application symlinks'
  task :symlinks do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      execute "rm #{release_path}/config/database.yml"
      execute "ln -s #{shared_path}/config/database.yml #{release_path}/config/database.yml"
      execute "ln -s #{shared_path}/config/secrets.yml #{release_path}/config/secrets.yml"
      execute "ln -s #{shared_path}/bin/passenger #{release_path}/bin/passenger"
    end
  end

  after :finishing, 'deploy:cleanup'
  after 'deploy:updated', 'deploy:symlinks'

end

namespace :setup do
  desc 'Copy the secrets.yml and database.yml files'
  task config: [ 'config/secrets.yml', 'config/database.yml' ] do |t|
    on roles(:all) do
      execute "mkdir -p #{shared_path}/config"
      t.prerequisites.each do |file|
        upload! file, "#{shared_path}/config"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

In our `config/deploy/staging.rb` file:

```
set :stage, :staging

# Simple Role Syntax
# ==================
# Supports bulk-adding hosts to roles, the primary
# server in each group is considered to be the first
# unless any hosts have the primary property set.
role :app, %w{deploy@208.94.36.146}
role :web, %w{deploy@208.94.36.146}

set :rails_env, "staging"
```

Our staging server bin folder:

[image: staging server bin folder]

You can see the application is making it to the box with the current releases setup:

[image: release setup]

Our current application on the server:

[image: application]

Our current application `config` directory:

[image: application config]

Comment: I'm a little confused. Are you using Chef to do the deploy or cap?

Comment: @coderanger I just updated to make that more clear. We used chef to build the server, and use cap to deploy to the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming passenger isn't in the Gemfile which is would cause the binstub to not get created. Is that the issue?